# Joint Angles with Kinect. (Absolute Beginner)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, kinect, angle

(a)Hello I am an absolute beginner in C# Programming. I just got a new Kinect Sensor and installed the SDK v1.0 . My aim is to correctly calculate the angles of joints in human body and subsequently perform a gait analysis. I have no understanding whatsoever of C++ or C# or Visual Studio.

(b)I saw the Kinect Skeletal Viewer Application which comes with the SDK,but I am not sure how the joints and segment lengths are defined. 
Some body please tell me the exact and complete procedure from absolute starting.

Comment: If you have no understanding of programming, this is not the site for you. I'd recommend that you look for a programming tutorial site (there are many excellent ones to choose from, including Microsoft's own). Learn some fundamentals before trying to work with your Kinect, because interacting with the Kinect will add many layers of complexity to your project that will be confusing for a beginner. Later, when your understanding is stronger and you have specific questions that you want to ask, Stackoverflow will be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you want to get the joints from the detected skeletons joints. Then, using the location of those joints, you can preform algorithms to find the distance or bone segments between the joints, or find the angle of a joint between two others. You can get a joint using

```
//Using C#
//In AllFramesReady
Joint joint = skeleton.Joints[JointType.code];

//get distance in 3D
double distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(joint.Position.X, 2) + Math.Pow(joint.Position.Y, 2) + Math.Pow(joint.Position.Z, 2));
```

However, using Kinect is a pretty advanced starting place for programming. It uses Events, Multithreads, and other advanced techniques. I would follow @DanPuzey 's advice and buy a book to teach you about programming, or follow a tutorial series. There are plenty of choices as he said, and once you understand the basics, you can start using Kinect. I personally cannot recommend any above the average books, but just using C# for Dummies 2010 helped me get down basic techniques. I know that programming can be hard at first, but I want you to know that it does get easier for a while. There are plenty of great resources on the internet to help you, including here! I hope you will use SO if you cannot find any answers elsewhere. Good luck!